# MudDialog with FullScreen, MudAppBar and scrollable content

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I would like to create a dialog

- FullScreen
- At the top fixed MudAppBar
- Content shall be scrollable

Here is how I solved:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOGHkJkUJApPdTVd
The issue is for the last element is kinda cut/overlapped I have tried to add bottom margin but did not work.

Comment: You can change the max-height to lower than 100vh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set max-height to `calc(100vh - (var(--mud-appbar-height) + 16px))`
with 16px is of margin-top you set but I suggest you set 32px so it looks better.
Here is the code of MudStack:

```
<MudStack Style="max-height: calc(100vh - (var(--mud-appbar-height) + 32px)); height: auto;  overflow-y: scroll;margin-top:32px;" >
```